# Trimming user profile information ruins joke

Tags: bug, profile-page

My current user profile info is as such:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> echo $GREETING, I am $NAME, working at $WORKPLACE in $LANGUAGE.
>
> echo $WITTY_COMMENT;
> ```
>
> Complaints, rants, comments and/or fanmail?  [Contact
>   Me](http://rkoutnik.com/contact.html)

The first bit `#!/bin/sh` is a [Shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (the whole thing being metacommentary* on the typical user profile).

Whenever I try to edit my user profile, the contents are trimmed, removing the first four spaces, leading to this wonderfully wrong profile (this usually happens when I'm editing a different section, such as my hat):

> ## !/bin/sh
>
> ```
> echo $GREETING, I am $NAME, working at $WORKPLACE in $LANGUAGE.
>
> echo $WITTY_COMMENT;
> ```
>
> Complaints, rants, comments and/or fanmail?  [Contact
>   Me](http://rkoutnik.com/contact.html)

(Man, I must really like malformed shebang lines)

I'd assume that ditching the trimming would cause many other problems, but can we special-case a profile starting with four spaces?

*And now I'm commenting on the metacommentary, meaning that was metametacommentary, that statement was metametametacommentary, this is on the meta site, AAAAAHHHHH

Comment: Can you put, say, an HTML comment _before_ your code block?

Comment: You could try wrapping it in `<code>...</code>` instead of the indent; although it seems to work fine for me too.

Comment: have you tried wrapping in backticks? \``#!/bin/sh`\` - it looked like code in preview of my profile

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there are workarounds.  I'm reporting a bug/unexpected behavior.

Comment: consider [edit]ing above clarification into the question (readers tend to ignore comments - though I upvoted yours to help them find it easier)